# Native SSO on AWS Cognito using Okta IdP

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, okta

Does anyone know if Cognito supports Okta [native SSO](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/11/12/native-sso)?
I am trying to integrate with an AWS Cognito flow using Okta as an external idP.

You can find more on the design on [Okta SSO](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/configure-native-sso/main/#exchange-existing-tokens-from-client-1-for-new-tokens-for-client-2).

--
I am working on a solution that authenticates an embedded view in a mobile app without needing to show any prompt to the user if they are already logged in. A web-SSO flow will trigger an "iOS prompt" every time the embedded view is being accessed. This embedded view is from a third party that uses Cognito while the mobile app uses Okta.

Here's more info on the prompt -https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/01/13/mobile-sso

Answer (score 0):

Cognito works with Okta based on browser communication, regardless what you choose: SAML or OIDC integration between Cognito and Okta.

So if you envision that you'll get this flow invoked through a browser, I don't see any difference between native or web-SSO.

But if you hope to use a token obtained from Okta through native-SSO to sign-into Cognito, I'd lean towards saying "no".

Maybe someone with real experience corrects me though.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, yes, I am looking to use the id_token or secret obtained from native-SSO to sign in to Cognito.

Comment: --
I am working on a solution that authenticates an embedded view in a mobile app without needing to show any prompt to the user if they are already logged in. The web-SSO flow will trigger an "iOS prompt" every time the embedded view is being accessed. This embedded view is from a third party that uses Cognito while the mobile app uses Okta.

Here's more info on the prompt -https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/01/13/mobile-sso

Comment: I don't think Cognito supports that, Gozie. But as I said, I might be wrong. You need to check AWS documentation for that too